# simplify my code in C++ below

Tags: c++, function, formula, block

I want to create a program which is able to calculate the surface area, volume, and circumference. for your additional info, I am studying about function, I has just learned about C++ about a week.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int getPostP(string msgP)
{
    int Ppost= 0.000;

    do
    {
        cout << msgP << endl;
        cin >> Ppost;

        return Ppost;
    } while(Ppost<= 0);
}

int getPostL(string msgL)
{
    int Lpost= 0.000;

    do
    {
        cout << msgL << endl;
        cin >> Lpost;

        return Lpost;
    } while(Lpost<= 0);
}

int getPostT(string msgT)
{
    int Tpost = 0.000;

    do
    {
        cout << msgT << endl;
        cin >> Tpost;

        return Tpost;
    } while(Tpost <= 0);
}

int surfaceArea(int Psur, int Lsur, int Tsur)
{
    return (2*Psur*Lsur)+(2*Psur*Tsur)+(2*Lsur*Tsur);
}

int volume(int Pvol, int Lvol, int Tvol)
{
    return (Pvol*Lvol*Tvol);
}

float circumference(int Pcir, int Lcir, int Tcir)
{
    return 4*(Pcir+Lcir+Tcir);
}

int main()
{
    int P = getPostP("enter the P of your block");
    int L = getPostL("enter the L of your block");
    int T = getPostT("enter the T of your block");


    float surfAreaBlock = surfaceArea(P, L, T);

    float volBlock = volume(P, L, T);

    float cirBlock = circumference(P, L, T);

    cout << "block which have P = " << P << " and L = " << L << " and T = "<< T << " have surface area = " <<
        surfAreaBlock << " and volume = " << volBlock << " and cirBlock = " << cirBlock;

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe one of you want to rewrite and add some comment, which parts are able to simplify, so I can understand easier.

Comment: What is the purpose of `do while` with an **unconditional `return`** inside it ?

Comment: `getPostP`, `getPostL`, `getPostT` functions are identical...

Comment: do while making sure the user input integer >0;

Comment: i know its identical, but i cant make it simply. i dont have any clues

Comment: You can remove `getPostL`, `getPostT` and do `int P = getPostP("enter the P of your block");
    int L = getPostP("enter the L of your block");
    int T = getPostP("enter the T of your block");` currently. (renaming `getPostP` to `input_integer` might be better too).

Comment: I meant that your `return` should not be in the do while block.

Comment: ***i know its identical, but i cant make it simply*** If it is identical then you only need 1 of them. Just change the string passed.

Comment: `int` isn't good at holding `float` values i.e. 0.000f

Comment: goto https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you should make all of your integer inputs into `double` instead of `int`, since it's expected that your inputs won't necessarily be an exact integer amount (probably). Also you can get rid of all of your duplicate functions for entering the parameters. Change it to a single function and call that one for each variable.

```
double getInput(const std::string& prompt)
{
    double input(0.0);
    do
    {
        std::cout << prompt << "\n-> " << std::flush;
        // forces input to be a double type
        while (!(std::cin >> input))
        {
            std::cout << "\n-> " << std::flush;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(256, '\n'); ///< could use streamsize::max here
        }
    } while (input <= 0.0);  ///< make sure it's positive
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I would be more likely to declare all as `double` as there is little to no saving on 64-bit procs and the 19 additional mantissa bits really do help accuracy and rounding.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin excellent point I've changed them from `float` to `double`